# What is correction needed to remove this error?

Tags: matlab, variable-assignment, submission

when I prompted submit()

then the output was as

Warning: File: submitwithConfiguration.m Line: 4 Column: 3

"parts" is used as a function or command and then as a variable name

Using "parts" as both a function and a variable name in same scope will error for future release.

Similarly same error for different line and column for " submissionUrl

this in Matlab online for submission assignment on Coursera

Comment: I don't know any Matlab, but I think the answer is right there in the warning - use different names for your functions and variables in the same scope.

Answer (score 1):

the answer seems to be in your post. "**Using "parts" as both a function and a variable name in same scope will error for future release**". Change the name of the variable or of the function, but don't use the same name for a function and variable in the same scope.

Comment: yes.since it was a warning it doesn't affected the submission and the output in Matlab. Finally it has been submitted.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because variable parts has the same name as of parts(conf) function in file ex1/lib/submitWithConfiguration.m 
Make the following changes to resolve this : 
Line 04 - `parts_1 = parts(conf);` 
Line 92 - `function [parts_1] = parts(conf)` 
Line 93 - `parts_1 = {};` 
Line 98 - `parts_1{end + 1} = part;` 
Basically, you just  need to rename the variables. 
Same thing is happening with one more variable, so make the following changes : 
Line 66 - `submissionUrl_1 = submissionUrl();` 
Line 68 - `responseBody = getResponse(submissionUrl_1, body);`